# Loop exits unexpectedly Python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop, ascii-art

I am making a program which takes a file with A-Z written in ASCII art. The program takes 3 lines of input: Hight, Width and the word that is to be written (All caps and spaces). I have managed to get the program to print the first letter that is iterated but, for some reason, it seems the for loop I set up just stops.

```
temp = []
hi = input('Height: ')
wi = input('Width: ')
tx = input('Text: ')
fi = open("font.txt")
for n in range(len(tx)):
    for i in tx:
        temp = cd[i]
        var1 = int(temp[0])
        ra1 = (var1 * int(hi))
        ra1n = (ra1 + int(hi))
        temp = []
        lines = fi.readlines()
        print(''.join(lines[ra1:ra1n]), end='')
```

This is what it outputs

```
Height: 8
Width: 9
Text: WOW

|\     /|
| )   ( |
| | _ | |
| |( )| |
| || || |
| () () |
(_______)
```

Comment: cd is a dictionary. The keys are every upper-case letter in the alphabet. the values are the letters would be positions in the file if hi(height) and wi(width) were equal to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to reread `font.txt` without rewinding the file position.

Either add a `file.seek(0)` call, or read the file *once* outside of the loop; using `lines = fi.readlines()` outside of the loop is going to be more efficient than using `fi.seek(0)` every time.

You also have a loop too many; you don't need to loop over `range(len(tx))` here, because you already loop over `tx` itself.

```
with open("font.txt") as fi:
    lines = fi.readlines()

for character in tx:
    var1 = int(cd[character])
    ra1 = (var1 * int(hi))
    ra1n = (ra1 + int(hi))
    print(''.join(lines[ra1:ra1n]), end='')
```

Comment: Thanks man. That extra loop was put in to see if it changed anything but I forgot to take it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try `file.seek(0)` in loop before `lines = fi.readlines()`.

```
    temp = []
    hi = input('Height: ')
    wi = input('Width: ')
    tx = input('Text: ')
    fi = open("font.txt")
    for n in range(len(tx)):
        for i in tx:
            temp = cd[i]
            var1 = int(temp[0])
            ra1 = (var1 * int(hi))
            ra1n = (ra1 + int(hi))
            temp = []
            fi.seek(0) # Here
            lines = fi.readlines()
            print(''.join(lines[ra1:ra1n]), end='')
```

or open the `file` in loop.

```
temp = []
hi = input('Height: ')
wi = input('Width: ')
tx = input('Text: ')
for n in range(len(tx)):
    for i in tx:
        temp = cd[i]
        var1 = int(temp[0])
        ra1 = (var1 * int(hi))
        ra1n = (ra1 + int(hi))
        temp = []
        fi = open("font.txt") # Here
        lines = fi.readlines()
        print(''.join(lines[ra1:ra1n]), end='')
```